# Issue with (right) slide in navigation bar overflowing body

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I am not able to solve the problem with my code. I was working on a right slide-in navigation panel. But when the panel is triggered in its non-active  state from its active state, the body overflows about x-axis.

Here's the code i have written

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.menu').toggleClass('active')
  })
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
.menu, .toggle{
  position:absolute;
}
.menu{
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:-300px;
  width:300px;
  background:green;
  transition:.22s;
}
.menu.active{
  right:0;
}
.toggle{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="toggle"></div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/ayushgx/pen/mYgyJe

I've already tried `overflow-x: hidden` in my code but nothing seems to be working accurately.

I've also found a pen everything he does in his code I've already did but nothing works out for me

Here's the pen: 
https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/grOZxx

I dont know if i am missing out something

As the code is working perfectly in desktop browser but not working in the mobile browsers. 
But in the given pen by erikterwan it works perfectly for both mobile and desktop

Comment: Do you have a `<div class='body'>` because you css is expecting one but you've not included it in your html here

Comment: Note: All the code needs to be in the question (not in a codepen).  Have a read of [mcve] and maybe create a snippet here to demonstrate.

Comment: Added a `<body>` to your codepen and it seems to work ok: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYGPNb is there any other issue?  Otherwise suggest close as a typo/unproducible

Comment: Yes that was a silly typo and now it works but only in the browser and not on the mobile devive

Comment: There's no mention of mobile in your question - please include all relevant information *in the question* (I've added the tag)

Answer (score 0):

Because your menu and toggle are positioned absolutely, the parent container must include `position: relative`:

```
.body{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Note that I have added code to the codepen to ensure that the height of the menu is as expected:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVmPzy

This should now work on mobile.

Comment: In desktop browser it works fine. However in mobile browsers it is not working.